# Laravel clone related models as well with replicate method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working inside a Laravel 10 project running PHP 8.1. I have two models, a `BuyerTier` and a `BuyerTierOption`. The options are linked to the `BuyerTier`. I need to be able to clone the `BuyerTier` with any related options to a "(Clone)" variant.

My code is working in that it does clone the parent `BuyerTier`, but isn't cloning the related options, what am I missing here to do this?

```php
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Company $company, Buyer $buyer, Request $request, BuyerTier $tier)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $tier);

    // if cloning tier
    if ($request->boolean('just_clone')) {
        try {
            $tier = $tier->load([
                'options'
            ]);

            $clonedTier = $tier->replicate();
            $clonedTier->name = $tier->name . ' (Clone)';
            $clonedTier->save();

            return new ApiSuccessResponse($clonedTier, [
                'message' => "We've successfully cloned this tier.",
            ], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'message' => 'Unable to clone buyer tier, please try again in a few minutes.',
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the original options, and store them to the cloned tier, something like this:

```
$clonedTier->save();

$tier->options->each(function($option) use ($clonedTier) {
    $clonedTier->options()->save($option);
});
```